# How to get only deleted records from an Ext js Grid store?

Tags: extjs, extjs3, gridpanel

I have a grid store and I am able to get modified data using

`var modifiedData = store.getModifiedData();`

Now I want to get deleted records (I am using ExtJs 3).

I tried using `var deletedData = store.getRemovedRecords();` but I guess this property is available in ExtJs 4.

I just want to fetch the records that are deleted from the grid.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default this is not possible.

ExtJS 3.x is only capable of tracking modified records (out of the box). Deleted (removed) records get removed completely. But there is one thing you can do; The store will fire the remove event for **each** record with the record itself as second argument. You may use this to create your own array of removed records. The implementation would be really simple I guess. You can do it per instance or create a whole new storetype by extending. But I guess the later is not really needed here.

Here is a example. Note that you might need take care of other events to clear the removedList.

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    removedList: [],
    listeners: {
        clear: function(store) {
              store.removedList =  [];
        },
        load: function(store) {
              store.removedList =  [];
        },
        remove: function(store, record, index) {
              store.removedList.push(record);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Check these two links out. They might be helpful.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?58888-Store-find-deleted-added-records
mi
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?15671-Ext.data.Store-with-persistence

Comment: You didn't gave any answer at all you just posting links. The links may break and this answer is worthless then. In addition: both links are about older versions of ExtJS (1.x / 2.x) You should fix your answer